# Cannot import visual studio .ltrar load test files into local machine db

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a load test server in an environment that gets dropped and recreated thus I need to export my load test results for future reference.

The problem however is that when I or anyone else attempts to import the .ltrar files to our local machine they fail to import giving the following message.

> Import load test result failed.
>
> SQLState = 23000, NativeError = 2627
>
> Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL
>   Server]Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   'PK__LoadTest__2CBF95903AC5BDB7'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   object 'dbo.LoadTestSqlTrace_Import1'. The duplicate key value is
>   (740).
>
> BCP copy in failed

My initial thought was to delete and recreate my local db which didn't work.
I have tried creating fresh exported files of multiple test runs which also didn't work.
I have tried on other colleagues machines which also don't work.

My server setup is a VS2012 instance pointing to a controller with one agent and a SQL server each on a separate VM. I am trying to import them to the most up to date version of VS2017 to my local device.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the Visual Studio versions from where the files are exported and where they should be imported. There was a change to the database layout around version 2012, that may be the problem. Please also describe how you export and import the files, i.e. do you use the load test import and export commands in Visual Studio?

Comment: @AdrianHHH my workstation is running the latest 2017 and the test rig is running 2012. I am exporting from the open and manage results window then importing the file back into my local machine in the same way.

Comment: I think you have incompatible versions of Visual Studio, but I do not have the files and I cannot find the web pages to validate that belief. Several Microsoft web pages have recently vanished. Visual Studio 2012 is an antique, there have been at least two other versions between 2012 and 2017. You might be able to check the version compatibility by comparing the `loadtestresultsrepository.sql` files located in folders such as `\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio {{version}}\Common7\IDE` of the two machines.